# Match any single character expect a final one

Tags: regex

I have this regex (https://regex101.com/r/2vZqGe/1):

```
(?P<url>http:\/\/(?:www|subdomain)\.domain.(?:com|net|org)\/folder1\/folder2\/(?P<path>(?P<uid>[0-9]*?)\/(?P<filename>.*?)\.(?P<extension>\w{3,4})))
```

Test string:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet http://subdomain.domain.org/folder1/folder2/00014647/header.jpg
Lorem ipsum
http://subdomain.domain.org/folder1/folder2/00014647/header1.jpg

http://subdomain.domain.org/folder1/folder2/00014647/header1.jpg lorem ipsum http://subdomain.domain.org/folder1/folder2/00014647/header1.jpg

http://subdomain.domain.org/folder1/folder2/00014647/head.er1.jpg
```

The last line of the test string have a filename with a dot (that may happen and I want to match it) so I thought, in order to match it correctly, I can remove the lazy quantifier in the filename group:

```
(?P<url>http:\/\/(?:www|subdomain)\.domain.(?:com|net|org)\/folder1\/folder2\/(?P<path>(?P<uid>[0-9]*?)\/(?P<filename>.*)\.(?P<extension>\w{3,4})))
```

But as you see for multiple patterns in the same line, it matches the whole line: https://regex101.com/r/2vZqGe/2

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Can you update the question with the patterns and the example data instead of the links only?

Comment: Can't you use `\S*` instead of `.*?`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew https://regex101.com/r/2vZqGe/4

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/2vZqGe/5. Actually, never run a regex on markup texts, only run them on plain text.